# NancyFx testing: The type or namespace Bootstrapper cannot be found

Tags: c#, .net, testing, nancy

**Update**: I resolved my problem substituting

```
var directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof (Bootstrapper).Assembly.CodeBase);
```

With

```
var directoryName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

So test work fine now. Anyway i leave question open in case someone could make the original code working (may be explaining why the Bootstraper is better than my solution :) so i can understand why is used here

**Original Question**

I'm just working with Nancyfx in C#, but i'm just restart to work in last week on c# and probably i'm missing a lot of concept related to dot.net and c#, will study about those in this weekend

Trying to create some test for a nancy module (i use Nunit and helper test class of NancyFx) i have the problem that those tests have to use the Path of the project for which i write the test for(that is for example i write those test in TestProject and i'm testing SelfHostNancyProject).
So i need to resolve this problem definitively (actually i manually copied the Views directory of project SelfHostNancyProject in the Views directory of TestProject).
But copying around those dir/files even with an automatically post-build command is not the best way.

I discover this solution 
https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Nancy-Testing-View-Location
but copying the code of class TestingRootPathProvider  inside my code i have the error

> The type or namespace Bootstrapper cannot be found

```
public class TestingRootPathProvider : IRootPathProvider
{
  private static readonly string RootPath;

  static TestingRootPathProvider()
  {
    var directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof Bootstrapper).Assembly.CodeBase);

    if (directoryName != null)
    {
      var assemblyPath = directoryName.Replace(@"file:\", string.Empty);
      RootPath = Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "..", "..", "..", "Escape.Web");
    }
  }

  public string GetRootPath()
  {
    return RootPath;
  }
}
```

But hanging around with google i can't find a solution. I see that seems something related to app inizialization 
[What are Bootstrappers/Bootstrapping in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968040/what-are-bootstrappers-bootstrapping-in-c-sharp)

But in any case i don't understand which import i have to do (if any) to resolve the problem or may be there is something i'm missing.

Comment: Can you put you answer below, it is OK if you have answered your own question.

Comment: Ok thank you , done. @DaiBok can i accept my own answer?

Comment: yes, if you cant do it now, you may just need to wait a few days and then accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem substituting

```
var directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof (Bootstrapper).Assembly.CodeBase);
```

With

```
var directoryName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```